# Vertical/Custom close-minimise-resize buttons in Cocoa Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, custom-controls, titlebar

How is this possible?
iTunes has this too and was wondering how I could get a custom title bar and perhaps change
the colour of the bar too

Comment: Do you mean the navbar customization?

Comment: It's a tricky thing to name, I mean the bar which holds the minimise close and resize buttons